# How could I wrap a physicsBody around a triangle?

Tags: swift, skphysicsbody

Im using rectangleOfSize right now to wrap a physics body around my triangle but the physicsBody is too big. Is there a way I could make the rectangle smaller so its not sticking out too much. This is what Im using right now:

EDIT: I tried the polygonFromPath but the triangle physics body is like half the size of the actual triangle. I used this site http://insyncapp.net/SKPhysicsBodyPathGenerator.html to make the coordinates.

```
    topTriangle.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 0.5, self.size.height / 1.3)
    topTriangle.zPosition = 17
    topTriangle.runAction(sequenceAllThis)
    addChild(topTriangle)

    let offsetX = CGFloat()
    let offsetY = CGFloat()

    topTriangle.frame.size.width * topTriangle.anchorPoint.x;
    topTriangle.frame.size.width * topTriangle.anchorPoint.x;

    let path = CGPathCreateMutable()

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 66 - offsetX, 1 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 130 - offsetX, 136 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 3 - offsetX, 135 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0 - offsetX, 135 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 131 - offsetX, 135 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 1 - offsetX, 135 - offsetY);

    CGPathCloseSubpath(path)

    topTriangle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: path)
    topTriangle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    topTriangle.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    topTriangle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = GameOverCategory
    topTriangle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = HeroCategory
    topTriangle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = HeroCategory
    topTriangle.physicsBody?.mass = 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath:)`, which allows you to generate custom shapes from a path you define.

The path can be constructed in various ways. Two of the ways I know of are the `UIBezierPath` and `CGPathCreateMutable` classes.

Comment: I edited my code an used the polygonFromPath but the physics body is half the size of the actual triangle. Can you take a look at my code I updated it in the op?

Comment: I don't see offsetX and offsetY initialized in your code. Those are effectively useless as they contain a value of zero if you don't give it a default value.

Each statement of `CGPathAddLineToPoint` essentially draws 1 line. A triangle only consists of 3 sides, so 3 lines. It doesn't make sense that you made 5 statements. 

You should only require 2 `CGPathAddLineToPoint` calls, since `CGPathCloseSubpath` will connect the last point to the origin point as the third line.